# WPF ListBox Binding inside a Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I've created a custom control that allows the user to choose an item from a combobox and add it in a listbox.
The combobox itemsource is a parameter of the control as well as the DisplayMemberPath.

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DisplayMember, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

The ComboBox works fine, the issue is in the Listbox because I don't know how to setup up properly the binding, I tried this code in the DataTemplate of the Listbox:

```
<DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayMember, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" /></DataTemplate>
```

but I get this error:

> BindingExpression path error: 'DisplayMember' property not found on
>   'object' ''ContentPresenter' (Name='')

DisplayMember contains the name of the property, for instance FirstName, like it was in this way:

```
         <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Style>
```

Comment: Could you post the complete xaml code ?

Comment: Please *don't* post the complete XAML, but instead just post the *relevant* XAML. Please explain also your problem better... where is this `TextBlock` for example? What is the relationship between it and the `ListBox`?